# Drupal 6 knowing it's current environment

Tags: drupal

I want to write a utility function so my Drupal project knows if it's running on the development, staging or live server.

Something like:

```
function mymodule_is_development() {  
    return (//some condition) ? TRUE : FALSE;  
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this the Drupal way? Drupal's multisite functionality should be leveraged I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Environment Indicator](http://drupal.org/project/environment_indicator) and how it works. You can use the `settings.php` to set a variable, or store one in the database with [`variable_set`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/variable_set/6).

Comment: settings.php! Of course! Thanks for the link to the project too. It looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```php
global $base_url;
```